Relative date filter of last X month based on the selected date using DAX
How do I create a relative date filter it shows the last 3 month of the currently selected filter?
If I use native relative date filtering it always shows the last 3 month and it does not change when I change the date on the page.

Filter last X month with DAX based on the selected date
Show last 03 month = 

VAR _number_of_month_to_show = 3 -- Change the number to the number of month you want to show

VAR _startDate =
    CALCULATE(
        DATE(
            YEAR(MAX(DIM_Calendar[Start of Month])),
            MONTH(MAX(DIM_Calendar[Start of Month]))-_number_of_month_to_show,
            DAY(MAX(DIM_Calendar[Start of Month]))
        ),
        ALLSELECTED(DIM_Calendar)
    )

RETURN
IF(
    SELECTEDVALUE(DIM_Calendar[Start of Month]) > _startDate,
    1,
    0
)



Variable : _number_of_month_to_show

Change the variable to how many month you would like to show






Variable : _startDate

calculates the DIM_Calendar[Start of Month] of ALL Selected from the current filter context and subtracts the _number_of_month_to_show






RETURN:

Checks if the selected value of DIM_Calendar[Start of Month] is greater than _startDate

Returns 1 if it is TRUE
Returns 0 if it is FALSE








Add the DAX measure to the filters and set it to:

Show items when the value: is 1





Do have a look at the DAX Time intelligence functions.
Here is an example of what your measure could look like:
Is Last 3 Months =
  CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(DimDate),
    DATESINPERIOD(DimDate[Date], MAX(DimDate[Date]), -3, MONTH)
  ) > 0

